# Adding 'Select All' to Bootstrap Multiselect form/list

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap-4

I have a .NET web application with several views that allow for me to select from database tables.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3, and have the list generated, but I need to add a 'Select All' option so that you don't have to individually click all of the values.

Here's the section of the .cshtml file in question:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Products" class="control-label"></label>
     <select asp-for="Products" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.AllProducts" size="10"></select>
</div>
```

AllProducts is defined on one of my controllers and generates a list of products that is pulled from a model.

Based on some similar answers I've read, I take it I need to write in a JS script to add on the 'Select All' option, but most of the examples I've seen deal with an option list that is defined here as opposed to with ViewBag.

I tried something like this, but couldn't get it to work:

```
$(".multiselect", this.el).multiselect({
includeSelectAllOption: true
});
```

Any advice? Trying to see if I'm heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each multi-select you build using tag helpers, you can have an option with a class called `.select-all`, and then you can write some simple `javascript` to add the behaviors it needs: selecting all options except itself on click.

But before I show you the `javascript` code, I would strongly suggest not to use `ViewBag` to bring the list of available products to the view to build the dropdown options. You're already using a view model. Why not just define another property there to contain that instead?

```cs
// View model
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Products")]
    public int[] SelectedProducts { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<int, string> AvailableProducts { get; set; }
}

// Controller
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new DashboardViewModel
    {
        // Simulate getting data from persistence storage to form the view model
        AvailableProducts = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "Cabinet" },
            { 2, "Countertop" },
            { 3, "Sink" },
            { 4, "Faucet" },
            { 5, "Flooring" },
            { 6, "Tile" }
        }
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

```
@*View*@
@model DashboardViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SelectedProducts"></label>
    <select asp-for="SelectedProducts" class="form-control" 
        asp-items="new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableProducts, "Key", "Value")" size="10">
        <option class="select-all">- select all -</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then finally you can write some simple `javascript` for the click event of the `.select-all` option:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('select[multiple="multiple"]').on('click', 'option.select-all', function() {
            let $selectAllOption = $(this),
                $select = $(this).closest('select');

            // Select all options
            $('option', $select).prop('selected', true);

            // De-select the select-all option
            $selectAllOption.prop('selected', false);

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got this working with the javascript you provided. As far as the `Viewbag` selection, this is a working codebase that I did not develop. I may look into switching this over to using view models instead. Is there any major downsides to `Viewbag`, or why do you not recommend using it?

Comment: @JohnNann: please see this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337789/when-where-and-how-to-use-viewbag. My point was: since you're passing a view model to the view already, you may as well just define what you need there in the view model. But year since this is not your codebase I guess you might have to live with it :p